# Parenthesis and Quotes - is it really this simple?

Tags: javascript

```
if (url) {
    var parsedUrl = new URL(url);
    s.eVar17 = parsedUrl.href;
    s.eVar19 = parsedUrl.host;
    s.linkTrackVars = 'prop6,eVar6,prop4,eVar5,eVar17,eVar19';
    var ppvArray = s.getPercentPageViewed(s.pageName);
    s.eVar6 = s.prop6 = ppvArray[1] + "|" + ppvArray[2] + "|" + ppvArray[3];
}
```

As soon as I feel good enough with javascript, I encounter something that stumps me. 
I can't figure out why this piece of code is not firing.  It is supposed to track visitors from my website who EXIT my site and then visit the first page of a new website.  The websites are specific and are linked on my site.  But this code pulls the URL so that I can keep track of how many visits a new site gets.

I believe that I should have parenthesis around the defined of s.linkTrackVars.
And double quotes.
But can anyone give me clues to lead me in the right direction?

Here's what I think it should be:
**s.linkTrackVars=("prop6, eVar6, prop4, eVar5, eVar17, eVar19");**

Thanks!
Misty

Comment: What is `if (url)` supposed to do?

Comment: `v = (e)` is parsed mostly-identically to `v = e`, where `e` is an expression; the parenthesis do nothing in the given case. (There are some edge-cases with ASI, but those are not relevant here.)

Comment: What is `s`? How do you create this object?

Comment: There is no difference between any of these: `s.linkTrackVars = 'prop6,eVar6,prop4,eVar5,eVar17,eVar19';` or `s.linkTrackVars = "prop6,eVar6,prop4,eVar5,eVar17,eVar19";` or `s.linkTrackVars = ('prop6,eVar6,prop4,eVar5,eVar17,eVar19');`.  Parenthesis and double quotes are not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are dealing with serilization and deserilization of an array of objects; and you code should read something like;

```
var linkTrackVars = { eVar17: somevalue ,eVar19: somevalue,...};
```

To serilize, use a JSON format like;

```
var myTextSerilizedVersion= JSON.stringify(linkTrackVars);
```

and to deserilize back to an object again, use

```
var linkTrackVars = JSON.parse(myTextSerilizedVersion);
```